# Javafx canvas content disappears

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I'm trying to visualize the process of solving the travelling salesman problem using the 2-opt-change algorithm but sometimes it seems like the execution of the program gets stuck and the window freezes without any error.
Sometimes even the lines drawn on a canvas disappear.

[image: It shold look like this:]

[image: But it looks like this:]

Some help would be nice.

Here's the drawing code:

```
 int numCities = getNumOfCities();
        Order currentOrder = data.getCurrentOrder();
        if (newValue) {
            GraphicsContext gc = canvasCities.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvasCities.getWidth(), canvasCities.getHeight());
            gc.setStroke(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));
            gc.setLineWidth(1);
            gc.setFill((Color.GRAY));
            for (int i = 0; i < currentOrder.getSize(); i++) {
                City current = data.getCities()[currentOrder.getValue(i)];
                City next;
                if ((i + 1) > numCities - 1) {
                    next = data.getCities()[currentOrder.getValue(0)];
                } else {
                    next = data.getCities()[currentOrder.getValue(i + 1)];
                }



                gc.fillOval(current.getX() - 5, current.getY() - 5, 10, 10);
                gc.strokeLine(current.getX(), current.getY(), next.getX(), next.getY());

            }

            if(!(data.getBestEver()==null)) {
                Order best = data.getBestEver();
                gc.setStroke(new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
                gc.setLineWidth(3);
                gc.setFill((Color.GRAY));
                for (int i = 0; i < best.getSize(); i++) {
                    City current = data.getCities()[best.getValue(i)];
                    City next;
                    if ((i + 1) > numCities - 1) {
                        next = data.getCities()[best.getValue(0)];
                    } else {
                        next = data.getCities()[best.getValue(i + 1)];
                    }


                    gc.fillOval(current.getX() - 5, current.getY() - 5, 10, 10);
                    gc.strokeLine(current.getX(), current.getY(), next.getX(), next.getY());

                }
            }
            repaint.set(false); //boolean that indicated if something changed and a repaint is necessairy
        }
```

Comment: Which thread does this code run on? What is `repaint` and what should be the effect of setting it to `false`?

Comment: The code is run by the thread that executes the algorithm. `Repaint` is a observable boolean that triggers the repaint when it is set to `true`. Setting it to `false` makes the next repaint possible.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a scene that is displayed from threads other than the JavaFX application thread. (see `Platform.runLater`)

Comment: Thank's that was the problem. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the multithreading part. After converting the paint part into a runnable that was invoked using `Platform.runLater()` it works fine.

Thank's to all who spent time on thinking about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> but sometimes it seems like the execution of the program gets stuck
>   and the window freezes without any error.

JFX consumes lots of resources...especially with Canvas and Shapes (e.g. recursive Group, etc.) If it got stuck it could be the "stack" was on the brink of overflow. Try with -Xss[nnM] where nn is any number, M stands for Megabytes. Example -Xss16M : Stack with 16MB for JFX threads. If it still behaves "weirdly" then combine -Xss with -Xms (for the heap).

Comment: Thank's for the fast answer but the problem occurs anyway. I tried -Xss1024M and -Xms1024M. I got a BufferOverflowException

Comment: BufferOverflow by 1G stack is a bit too large, isn't it? Just increase step-by-step 8, 16, 32, ... MB I have recently problem with the rendering of SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) where  "groups" are nested 32K times ! And my app stands still. After a long research and trial my app starts to run with up 8MB stack.

Comment: After trying a bit I got a BufferOverflowException and a "java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: 67".

Comment: Hi SF23. As said, JFX Canvas and JFX Shapes (e.g. SVGPath, Polygon, etc.) consume a lot of resources. Further: the underlaying part of JFX seems to work intensively with Recursiveness and that worsens the matters. If I have a complete part of your codes I might be able to reproduce the problem and have a chance to look for a solution.